# using gdscript procotcol buffers

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, gd, godot, integrated

I have an artificial intelligence model with Python, can I integrate this artificial intelligence model into the godot section, I use gdscrpt in the godot section, does gdscript support protocol buffers?

`protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-gdscript=/path/to/plugin --gdscript_out=. object_recognition.proto`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Godot has no built-in support for this. There seems to be some third party addons, I do not know how well they work.